# passing a function as a prop to component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this Reactjs code I have main code in app.js in addition to component code (filter.js), I'm only trying to print the value of the DDL selected option in console on Change using sortProducts and filterProducts functions by passing them as props to filter component.
I spent so many hours but I don't know why whatever I change the console remain empty, it can't see onchange function. Can you please help?

App.js code:

```
    import React from "react";
import data from "./Mobilesdata.json";
import Products from "./Components/Products";
import Filter from "./Components/Filter";
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      products: data.products,
      size: "",
      sort: "",
    };
  }
  sortProducts(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }

  filterProducts(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="grid-container">
        <header>
          <a href="/">React Shopping Cart</a>
        </header>
        <main>
          <div className="content">
            <div className="main">
              <Filter count={this.state.products.length}>
                size={this.state.size}
                sort={this.state.sort}
                sortProducts={this.sortProducts}
                filterProducts={this.filterProducts}
              </Filter>
              <Products products={this.state.products}></Products>
            </div>
            <div className="sidebar">cart Items</div>
          </div>
        </main>
        <footer>All right Reserved </footer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Filter.js code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Filter extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="filter">
        <div className="filter-result">{this.props.count} products</div>
        <div className="filter-sort">
          Order{""}
          <select
            value={this.props.sort}
            onChange={this.props.sortProducts}
          >
            <option value="latest">Latest</option>
            <option value="lowest">Lowest</option>
            <option value="highest">Highest</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="filter-size">
          Filter{""}
          <select
            value={this.props.size}
            onChange={this.props.filterProducts}
          >
            <option value="All">All</option>
            <option value="Iphone">Iphone</option>
            <option value="Huawei">Huawei</option>
            <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `<Filter count={this.state.products.length}>` Your filter tag is closing to soon, so your props are never passed.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it works ..much appreciate